# add more dictionaries in Dictd

Tags: dictionary

I have added quite a few dictionaries to goldendict

However not sure how to add these dictionaries to dictd

When I query using "dict siphon",

it returns entries from wn, gcide, and moby-thesaurus,
not from the additional few dictionaries I have added to goldendict.

Not sure if dictd support wide ranging dictionary format like goldendict,

For those dictionary formats supported by dictd, how do I add them to dictd to be included in its search list ?

Answer (score 0):

The normal method of adding dictionaries is by editing

```
/etc/dict/dictd.conf
```

Example:

```
database eng-spa {
    data /usr/share/dictd/eng-spa.dict.dz
    index /usr/share/dictd/eng-spa.index   
}
```

... adds the English-Spanish dictionary installed by `dict-freedict-eng-spa`. For other dictionaries, copy and paste the above database declaration but make sure to change the database name, i.e. eng-spa, and also change the data and index paths above to specify the right files.

[From Arch WIKI on dictd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dictd#Configuration).

After changing the configuration the service needs to be reloaded (`dictd.service`)

> Not sure if dictd support wide ranging dictionary format like goldendict,

The other way round: Goldendict has [support](https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict) for [dictd](http://goldendict.org/) so it will be a matter of adding the correct directories.

Comment: When I look at the files in the additional dictionaries installed for goldendict, they are in .mdd, .mdx, .css file type, how do I convert these file format into .dict.dz and .index file in order to be included the /etc/dict/dictd.conf ?

Comment: https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/wiki/Supported-Dictionary-Formats link provides information that (.index and .dict.dz) is Dictd dictionary, and (.mdd, .mdx) is MDict dictionary,  so I will google to find out how to convert from MDict dictionary to Dictd dictionary in order to include in /etc/dict/dictd.conf

Comment: https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary this link seems to provide a tool to convert MDict to Dictd dictionary format, however, I don't know how to install pyglossary, can you help ?

Comment: I just downloaded the 2009 pyglossary file from https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyglossary/downloads, however, I encounter warning message "This type of file can harm your computer, do you want to keep pyglossary_2009...deb anyway ? Do I ignore this warning ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92416/discussion-between-raymondraymond1-and-rinzwind).